# Solr conditional spellcheck

Tags: php, solr, spell-checking

Environment : PHP, solr client, solr 7.2.1

I want to run my spellchecker if my /select query return nothing. Can i do it in a single query? Or i have to make conditional in my PHP,

im using index based spell checker :

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">indexchecker</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
      <str name="field">pagetext</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
      <!-- optional elements with defaults
      <str name="comparatorClass">freq</str> freq score(default)
      <str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.LevensteinDistance</str>
      <str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.JaroWinklerDistance</str>
      <str name="accuracy">0.5</str>
      -->
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you're running the select with `spellcheck=true`, the result will be present in the same request.

You can [tune when you want the spellchecker to be invoked](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/spell-checking.html) by adding a few parameters to your request:

**spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest**

> The maximum number of hits the request can return in order to both generate spelling suggestions and set the "correctlySpelled" element to "false".

**spellcheck.onlyMorePopular**

> Limits spellcheck responses to queries that are more popular than the original query.

Comment: hmm, yes its correct. In request handler /select, i can do query and activate spellchecker=true. But when i do this, ill always run select + spellchecker. I want something like select?q=some_term&[if numFound>0 then spellchecker=true], something like that, :)

Comment: Which is what the `spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest` is for? Or does that not work how you expect it to work?